# Apache authentication via sql in fedora/rhel/almalinux/rocky linux

Tags: linux, fedora, rhel, almalinux

on fedora I installed apache and mysql, I created the user with certain privileges and I populated the database, but I can't connect apache with sql. Can anyone help me on how to do it?

I've tried editing my httpd.conf file but nothing, I would expect when I put my ip address on the browser it looks for my credentials, I enter my database credentials and access the page

Comment: What do you use to link Apache to MySQL?  ex. PHP can be used.  Do you expect Apache to connect to MySQL directly?  It wont, you need some application to do that.  If you need a MySQL admin tool, you can use PHPMyAdmin, or other database admin tool for other languages (using CGI or something else).

Comment: I knew I had to use apache's mod_authn_dbd and configure my httpd.conf file

Comment: ah I am sorry, I understood the reverse, my bad.  I thought you wanted to use Apache to login into your database, not use the database as a user verification for your Apache pages.  My apologies.

Comment: no problem, I hope someone can help me